# How to get specific details on memory problems in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, memory, diagnostic

**Solution found below; will mark as answer when able**

Within the last week, I've been gettings some BSODs with a MEMORY_MANAGEMENT code. I ran the Windows Memory Diagnostic tool, and within a second of it running, it detected a hardware problem. Once the machine had rebooted and I logged in, I was greeted with a popup stating that there was a hardware problem with the machine and to contact the computer manufacturer.

There was just one problem though; I built the machine. I recently purchased some new RAM (within the last two months), but want to be able to determine if the RAM is actually the problem, or if it is some other component, before sending it in for RMA.

My machine specs are:

- OS: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
- Motherboard: ASUS P6X58D-E
- CPU: Intel Core i7 960
- RAM: 2x8GB modules of PNY XLR8 DDR3 1600 MHz
- SSD1: Samsung 840 EVO 250GB
- SSD2: Samsung 840 Pro 256GB
- HDD1: Western Digital Black 1TB

(All drives report OK with SMART)

Is there a way to determine what exact component is having the issue, or is the fact that it failed almost immediately with the Windows Memory Diagnostic, almost certainly mean it's the module itself, and not the memory controller on the board or CPU?

Comment: Do you have known good memory you can use to test and see if it the memory or a mobo problem? Its one or the other.

Comment: this can't be detected via software. test each RAM on it's own in each slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like (for now) it was a PEBKAC. I recently built my girlfriend a machine, and gave her the existing RAM that was in my system. I installed the RAM in her machine first, and when I went to put in my RAM, I put it in the wrong slots (A1 and A2 like in her machine, instead of A1 and B1 in mine). I looked at the manual for my motherboard and sure enough, I was wrong.

I ran the Memory Diagnostic tool again and no errors were reported.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that the ram were new and the system is old na.

Most probably the problem should be with dust... use a good blower to clean your cpu.. esp. The ram sockets. Dust in your ram sockets can cause severe problems like BSODs saying problem with memory as u explained.

Good Luck.

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question.  You are just throwing a bunch of wet noodles ( idea your ideas ) on the fridge thinking one might stick.